# How to select html element with namespace with Fizzler / HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack, fizzler

I am using Fizzler / HtmlAgilityPack to parse and extract elements from ASP.NET page file. In the asp.net file, we also use Telerik controls, e.g.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ... >
```

To extract this element , I used the methods below but not success. Can someone help on this please?

method#1:

```
HtmlDocument document = .....;

document.SelectNodes("telerik:RadGrid");
```

and it throws exception below:

[image: Exception]

Then I tried method#2:

```
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("telerik", "http://www.telerik.com");
var expr = XPathExpression.Compile("RadGrid");
expr.SetContext(manager);
var grids = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(expr);
```

There is no exception again. But grids is null even though the asp.net page contains markup of telerik:RadGrid.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your xpath is incorrect.
Please try this //*[name()='telerik:RadGrid'] as a namespace, it should work for elements with XML Namespace.

Comment: Thanks @Milan I tried this with method#1. It didn't throw out exception but the method still returns null for 'grids'.

Comment: You could test the xpath in chrome or firefox console to make sure that it selects what you need.